# Create row if it doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to do something like this:

```
if @item.exists?(:cron => "mycron")
  # redirect to item page
else
  # create new @item
end
```

Is there a simpler way to do it in Rails?

Maybe something like:

```
@item.create_if_not_exists(:cron => "mycron")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's called **[`find_or_create_by`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object)**

```
@item = Item.find_or_create_by_cron("mycron")
# redirect to item page
```

Comment: I think `find_or_create` is deprecated in rails 4 in favour of [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)